# Trying to use orbot/orfox (TOR) on Android on this website thats says Firefox 38 not supported need FIREFOX 45 or newer

Tags: orbot, firefox, update

Can somebody please help me, cant find a way to update browser through orbot which is basically tor on android cellphone , i tried on different types of androids each of them says the same thing ...
Trying to login my bitcoin account through tor(cellphone)
says firefox 38 is not supported need 45 or newer

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of Orbot (available through the Google Playstore or through [FDroid](https://f-droid.org/) from [The Guardian Project's repo](https://guardianproject.info/fdroid/) is based on the Firefox 52 series for Android.

If you are running the latest version from one of those sources, and the site still complains about the version number then either the sites user-agent detection is faulty *or* Orfox/Firefox for Android is missing a specific feature that the site is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like a fingerprinting attempt: I do remember mid-1990's, when we have had GIF's like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/Pc1abBsK9ucyQ/200.gif) "this site is designed for xxx" - there's absolutely NO REAL NEED for browser version checking nowdays: all modern browsers are standard-compliant. So the website tries to grab some info from you and/or fingerprinting you by browser's features. You better avoid using it even with the modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

I use orbot and astrill vpn regularly but I don't use Firefox. Currently I am using Chrome Beta and I have no problems.

I remember having such problems withy Firefox on my PC. Resolved by upgrading to the required version. Q: can you upgrade through Google Play? Google Play should discount the connection as it verifies through the phone. If it does not upgrade, then close orbot, upgrade and then restart orbot.

Also check the useragent if you have one. Try and remember which status you had when you registered. If you can, good. If not try and change but I will limit changs to one a day as the system will log access attempts and basically suspend acess if too many attempts. So be careful.

Can you install Chrome? If you can try to install Chrome Beta and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Download APKPure and see if in your installed apps if there is an update for you. It will be the same as when you update your apps and system apps on Google Play Store.

Comment: It absolutely will not be the same as when you update your apps on the play store. It will be significantly worse since it's being distributed through some entirely unverifiable platform. This is how you get malware.